# Why doesn't document.getElementById("thediv").forms[0] return any elements?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does `document.forms[0]` return something (the first form on the page), but `document.getElementById("thediv").forms[0]` does not return anything?

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YDaRW/)

On a more complex page, I would expect the be able to narrow down the scope of the browser's search for `form` elements by specifying an ID.

Comment: Why not just give the forms you're interested in IDs of their own and then you can find the relevant form directly with document.getElementByID on the form ID.  My guess to your question is that the document has a forms array, but an individual div does not.

Comment: @jfriend00 - That's certainly an option sometimes, but in this case I don't have the ability to change the client's markup.  With this question, I'm trying to understand why one way works and another doesn't.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forms` is a property of `document`.  `document.getElementById` is a function that returns an HTMLElement object.  This does not have a property called forms.  Look at jQuery if you'd like more logical javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Because there isn't such a property `forms` on DOM element objects, [only the `document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.forms).

Forms are still forms within the same page no matter where they're found in the document tree. If you need to grab a subset of forms on a page based on a certain parent element, you'll probably want to try a library like jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('thediv').getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
```